# $k$-largest eigenvalues symbol

Tags: math-mode, symbols, amsmath

how can i achieve this

[image]

in LaTeX to denote the `$k$`-largest eigenvalue of a Matrix?

Comment: `$\lambda^\downarrow_1(A)$`

Comment: Interesting notation.  I usually just use $\lambda_\text{max}$.

Comment: @JohnKormylo My gut feeling is that this notation belongs to some part of convergence definition (or whatever) :D

Comment: This notation is borrowed from bathias book matrix analysis.

Comment: @Sigur Care to write up an answer to get this off the unanswered list?

Comment: @JohnKormylo Why not just use `$\lambda_\max$` in your case?

Answer (score 3):

In math mode, we can insert the Greek letter by `\lambda`. Also, to insert subscript we use `^{}` and to subscript, `_{}`. To produce a down arrow, we use `\downarrow`.

So, if we insert everything together,

```
$\lambda^{\downarrow}_{1}(A)$
```

Fortunately, TeX is smart enough to simplify our life, so if the index contains a single command or letter or number, we can skip the braces, that is, equivalently,

```
$\lambda^\downarrow_1(A)$
```